# Introducing ability for interactive function to set show-paren-style

Tags: parentheses

I am using the following interactive function to enable `show-paren-mode`.
Would like to have the capability to change the style.  What can I do for such functionality to work?

```lisp
    (defun rk-bracemk-companion ()
      "Indicates counterpart character when matching bracketing pairs."
      (interactive)
    
      (show-paren-mode 1)
      (setq show-paren-delay 1.3)
    
      ;; Options: Style | `parenthesis', `expression', `mixed'
      (setq show-paren-style 'parenthesis))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defun rk-bracemk-companion (style)
  "Indicates counterpart character when matching bracketing pairs."
  (interactive "SStyle: ")

  (show-paren-mode 1)
  (setq show-paren-delay 1.3)

  ;; Options: Style | `parenthesis', `expression', `mixed'
  (setq show-paren-style style))
```

Allows free-text entry of any Lisp symbol (which is what `'parenthesis` etc are)